# Calculus problem engineering

Tags: calculus

You are working as a Junior Engineer for a small motor racing team. You have been given a proposed mathematical model to calculate the velocity (when t=0) of a car accelerating from rest in a straight line. The equation is:

$$v(t)=A\left(1- e^\frac{-5t}{tmax}  \right)$$

v(t) is the instantaneous velocity of the car (m/s)
t is the time in seconds
tmax is the time to reach the maximum speed in seconds
A is a constant.

t(0-28 m/s) 1.9 (s)   t(400m) 10.50 (s)   tmax  7.1 (s)

1. Identify the 
   ●   units of the coefficient A
   ●   physical meaning of A
   ●   velocity of the car at t = 0
   ●   asymptote of this function as t → ∞?

Comment: Set aside that the maximum velocity is never actually reached, what is the question here?

Comment: what is the physical meaning of A

Comment: Please update the original question. Also, what is the last line supposed to tell us?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show more effort. Also this line "t(0-28 m/s) 1.9 (s) t(400m) 10.50 (s) tmax 7.1 (s)" is completely unclear. Furthermore as I said before the max velocity can not be reached. Please include all of these points in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A miles per hour is the upper limit of the velocity of the car. 
How could you not know what v(0) is?
Notice v levels off at y = A.